# Hierarchical polygons for polygon clusters (e.g. state/county)

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, markerclusterer

I am wondering if it is possible for clusterMarkers in leaflet to cluster around predefined polygons rather than the algorithm defined polygons.

I would love to figure out how to do this and define my clustered polygons as states/counties. It seems someone did solve this but took their github down so I am out of luck. But at least I know it can be done.

I have the following code

```
getColor <- function(my.df) {
  sapply(my.df$value, function(value) {
  if(value <= 5) {
    "green"
  } else if(value <= 25) {
    "orange"
  } else {
    "red"
  } })
}
icons <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColor(my.df)
)


map <- my.df %>% 
    leaflet () %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(icon=icons, label=~as.character(freq), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
map
```

my.df is in the following format

```
longitude latitude freq
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    3
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    7
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    4
.
.
.
XX.xxx    XX.xxx    6
```

Further, if the cluster information could also display aggregate value for my.df$freq rather than the number of pins in the cluster, that would also be amazing!

I am not sure how to do this though or if there is even a clusterOption for this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it is possible for clusterMarkers in leaflet to cluster around predefined polygons rather than the algorithm defined polygons.

No.

What you *can* do, however, is categorize your points depending on the area they're in (e.g. one category per county/state), then create one cluster group *for each* category.

If your use case is simple, you might instead want to just count the number of data points in each area and plot the count on the centroid (or the pole of inaccessibility) of each area.